# How do we use letsencrypt SSL certificates in an IoT architecture

Tags: ssl, iot, lets-encrypt

We are building an IoT architecture consisting of a API gateway and other services deployed on the cloud. The server uses a letsencrypt SSL certificate, so it is possible to communicate over SSL with the server. There are a number of hardware devices which send data to the server. We want to use x.509 certificate based communication and authentication from the devices to the server. I have two questions in this regard,

1. Is it possible to use letsencrypt certificate to generate the x.509 based certificate which can be configured on the device. If yes, what are the steps to do so
2. Since a letsencrypt certificate expires after 90 days, does it mean that after every 90 days, we will have to renew the certificates on all the devices? If yes, is there any best practice to handle such situations

Comment: did you make any progress on this front?

Comment: Nope. Still using token based authentication from devices

Comment: ahh ok, so you create your certs with letsencrypt to establish a TLS connection with the server and the devices--with symmetric encryption. Then you generate JWT's or other types of tokens to authenticate the devices?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Let's Encrypt does not support intermediate certificates, so you wouldn't be able to generate your "own" certificates for your devices.